# OpenCV Haar Cascade Creation

Tags: opencv, cascade-classifier

I want to try create my own .xml file for my graduation project with this [reference](https://github.com/mrnugget/opencv-haar-classifier-training).

But I have a problem which stage 6 doesn't work.It gives error such as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/mergevec.py", line 170, in <module>
    merge_vec_files(vec_directory, output_filename)
  File "./tools/mergevec.py", line 120, in merge_vec_files
    val = struct.unpack('<iihh', content[:12])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I have found a solution which says find 0 size vector files and delete them.
But, I don't know which vector files are 0 size and how I can detect them.
Can you help about this please?

Comment: This github repo references opencv 2.x . Now opencv 4.x is a standard.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem when i changed it:

```
for f in files:
            with open(f, 'rb') as vecfile:
                content = ''.join(str(line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
                data = content[12:]
                outputfile.write(data)
except Exception as e:
    exception_response(e)
```

for it:

```
for f in files:
            with open(f, 'rb') as vecfile:
                content = b''.join((line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
                outputfile.write(bytearray(content[12:]))
except Exception as e:
    exception_response(e)
```

and like before i changed it:

```
content = ''.join(str(line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
```

for it:

```
content = b''.join((line) for line in vecfile.readlines())
```

because it was waiting for some str, and now it is able to receive the binary archives that we're in need.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try following this [guide](https://medium.com/@dikshitkathuria1803/training-your-own-cascade-classifier-detector-opencv-9ea6055242c2). It's more recent.